# Read from Excel File and Insert into Access

Tags: c#, excel, database, ms-access

I am new at coding and I have a problem: I use Apache Poi to read an Excel File with only one column and about 20 rows. I want to read that information and insert it into my Access Database but I couldn't figure out how.

This is my first method:

```
Workbook readWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(FileChooser.FileChoose()));
Sheet sheet = readWorkbook.getSheetAt(4);
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

String cellValue = null;
for (int i = 16; i < 20; i++) {  //Statt 20 soll hier 39
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    if(row == null) {
        continue;
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        if(cell == null) {
            continue;
        }
        cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        System.out.print(cellValue + "\n");
    }
}
return cellValue;
```

And this is my Insert Code:

```
try {
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+FileChooser.FileChoose());
    Statement stment = conn.createStatement();

    String query = "INSERT INTO Maschine (com_id, typ, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v) VALUES ('"+DatenBankInsert.ForEachLoop()+"')";
    stment.executeUpdate(query);

    System.out.println("successfull");
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Not connected"+e);
}
return null;
```

Comment: What error do you get? Those apostrophes in Values clause could be an issue.

Comment: Hello, this is the error code:
Not connectednet.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 row column count mismatch

I have also in the database the exact same columns

Comment: Your insert statement has 24 columns yet you are inserting a single VALUE. How many columns are in Maschine? What is the result of `DatenBankInsert.ForEachLoop()`?

Comment: Yes, DatenBankInsert.ForEachLoop() returns 24 Values from the Excel Sheet. And I want to put it into the Insert Statement but I don't know how.

Comment: So why use Poi and not just Access import tools or VBA? If the Excel has only one column, why does your INSERT have 24 fields? Edit question with the error message and additional info.